# On-Air Now Feature - ExpressionEngine

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, expressionengine

EE  v2.5.3

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- 6 Radio Shows (Mon-Fri)
- 1 Radio Show (Sun)
- Default Setting (Logo)

I'd like to be able to tell EE the following:

```
If Monday - Friday AND
0600 - 1000 
Morning Show

else if

1000 - 1500
Midday Show

etc etc..

else if
Sunday AND
0600 - 1200
Sunday Show

else if 
1700-1900
Sunday Night Show

else 
Default display of Logo
```

My (non-working) Example:

```
<div id="in_studio_now_content" class="container_4">

{if
    '{current_time format="%l"}' == Thursday AND
    '{current_time format="%H%i"}' >= '1000' AND
    '{current_time format="%H%i"}' <= '1700'
}

<div class="showContainer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" class="container_1" />
    <div class="showInfo left">
        <h5>The Midday Show</h5>
    <p>with Jenn</p>
    <p class="timeslot">Weekdays 10:00 - 3:00 pm</p>
        <div id="facebookLike">F like 32k</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="showLink container_3">More about this show &rsaquo;</a>
</div><!-- /show -->

{/if}

</div><!-- studio content -->
```

Comment: How is it not working?  Is it generating errors? Incorrect data?

Answer (score 1):

This should sort you

```
{if
'{current_time format='%l'}' == 'Thursday' &&
'{current_time format='%H%i'}' >= '1000' &&'{current_time format='%H%i'}' <= '1700'}
```

Note that I've placed Thursday in single quotes and replaced your time formatting with single quotes also.

Comment: With this example, would it be able to handle the complexity of Mon-Friday and 2 Sunday Shows?

Comment: you'd have multiple if statements for each case. I wouldn't use {if:else}

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. I'm liking the simplicity in the answer from @jean St-Amand too

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a combination of [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) and [IFElse](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse), both from Croxton, to make this parse more quickly since it's a rather complex conditional.  How about something like this, for example?

```
{exp:switchee var="{current_time format='%l'}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday"}
       {exp:ifelse parse="inward"}
           {if '{current_time format="%H%i"}' >= '0600' AND '{current_time format="%H%i"}' <= '0959'}
               Morning show
           {if:elseif '{current_time format="%H%i"}' >= '1000' AND '{current_time format="%H%i"}' <= '1459'}
               Midday Show
           {/if}
       {/exp:ifelse}
     {/case}
     {case value="Saturday"}
         Do the same sort of thing for Saturday
     {/case}
     {case value="Sunday"}
         Do the same sort of thing for Sunday
     {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Also note here that I've adjusted the times by 1 minutes - otherwise, two conditions in the same set (because you are using equal to or less/greater than) could be true at the same time.

Comment: This looks logically sound :) I'll have to see about those two extensions you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely use [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) or [IfElse](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse) for complex conditionals.

Comment: Switchee and ifelse are both incredibly powerful and logical.  Worth using every time!

Comment: We installed those two modules and the sample code above but nothing outputs.

Comment: Actually, i have a small error in there - should be exp:switchee variable="" rather than just var="" - will you please give that a try?